# error while connecting to ldap server having simple authentication using java

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, connection

Below is snippet from my code:

```
public class CheckingUsers 
{   
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, LoginException 
{
    String URL = "ldap://myhostURL:389";
    String ldapServerSearchBase = "DC=abc,DC=xyz,DC=pqr"; 
    String principal = "CN=myCN,OU=PEOPLE,DC=abc,DC=xyz,DC=pqr";

    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, URL);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pswd);
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("connected");
        System.out.println(ctx.getEnvironment());

        // some stuff

        ctx.close();
}
}
```

I am new to this and I am getting this message while executing the code. Please help

[image]

When I stop the execution I get the below message:

[image]

Comment: You have a `NumberFormatException`.  Something is expecting a number but you have provided a non-numeric value. Unfortunately we can't tell from what you have posted.  The "terminated" message is normal.  What you need to do is not terminate it and let the exception be thrown. Then copy/paste the COMPLETE exception stack trace into your question (format as code i.e. paste it in then hilight and use the `{}` button).  Also, in general do not post images of code or stack traces.

Comment: Since the debugger can stop when Exception happened. Why don't you select  `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` and check the value of method arguments?